# Understanding "Scroll Update" in Chrome dev tools performance analysis

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

I took a performance recording of a web page from my web app using the Chrome dev tools `performance` tab. I mainly wanted to test the scrolling performance, so I scrolled the page while recording. Here are the screenshots from the recording:

[image: Performance Recording Frames and Main Thread]
[image: Performance Recording of Frames and other threads]

As you can see, I have selected one frame to inspect it in more detail. This frame took 33.8ms to render, hence giving me only 30 frames per second, instead of the desired 60 FPS. You can see from the picture that the majority of the time was taken up by `Scroll Update` process highlighted in purple bars under the `Input` tab. However, the graph does not give much information about what this `Scroll Update` really is? And why did it take so much of time?

The main thread and other threads like Rasterization are pretty much empty, so the usual suspects like `layout`, `painting`, `compositing`, are not to blame here. So I would like to know what the real cause for dropped frames here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Devtools profiler hides some stuff by default: [enable the experiments flag](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/customize#experiments), restart and open the experiments panel, then press the Shift key 6 times, and enable "show all events" and "V8 runtime" https://puu.sh/FwpAQ/abba5c40e0.png. You can also perform an even more advanced analysis by using `chrome://tracing`, look for tutorials.

Comment: Also try divide-and-conquer debugging: remove (or comment out) parts of your html/css and see if it changes something and continue the process recursively until you find the culprit. It could be that Chrome is slow with a particular kind of content like images or sticky/fixed position and so on, which might be a platform-specific problem.